# Filter while maintaining denominator in percentage from before filtering in Tableau

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I currently have a graph which displays a count as total and percentage markings (this is also on the rows shelf).  The entries have a dimension which has a status of Other Apps and Overdue.  However, on the graph I only want to show the Overdue data, while maintaining the correct percentage of the total which includes both Other Apps and Overdue.  When I try adding a filter to only show overdue, this changes my data so that they are all 100%, ignoring the On-Time count in the denominator due to the filter.  Is there a way that I can keep the calculation out of the total without showing the part of the bar for Other Apps count?

Here is a sample screenshot before filtering:

[image: Before Filtering]

Comment: Can you share the workbook or add screenshots?

Comment: I just attached a screenshot.  Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide that may help.  Unfortunately, I can't link the workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide 'Other Apps' (`right click > hide`). This way `Other Apps` won't be displayed, but still will be used to calculate the percentages.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you can right-click for this.  Where would I do this from? (Nice avatar btw)

Comment: True. It doesn't work after clicking on the bar chart. Turn the chart into text, hide the part you don't need, and then turn it into a bar chart. There might be a smarter way though.

Comment: It's not showing up as an option for me.  Perhaps it's because 'Other Apps' is part of the 'CurrentStatus 0' group?

Comment: Have you tried hiding 'Other Apps' when using 'Text tables' (in 'Show me' menu)?

Comment: I just tried that now and it solved the problem.  Thanks!